# Set Focus of TextBox inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, user-controls, mahapps.metro

I have a `UserControl` with just a `TextBox` inside it, this `TextBox` has some attached properties and some code behind, since I am going to use it in multiple Views, I created a `UserControl` with it to improve reusability and maintenance.

This `TextBox` is used for Search, so I trying to set it on Focus when the user makes a `Ctrl+F`, this works fine, the problem is, I can't make the `TextBox` focus, just the `UserControl` gets focused.

So the question is: How to redirect the `Focus` of the `UserControl` to the `TextBox` inside it?

I tried already:

```
protected override void OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox.SelectAll();        
    base.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(e);
}
```

and many other different combinations, like changing the order the `base` is called, or removing it...calling `this.TextBox.Focus()` which sets a StackOverFlow...verifying if `this.TextBox.IsFocused` doesn't work, it's always `false`...so... how can I achieve this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604091(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it, I changed the:

```
protected override void OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox.SelectAll();        
    base.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(e);
}
```

to:

```
protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox.SelectAll();        
    base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);
}
```

I guess the whole `RoutedEvents` interactions of bubbling and tunneling was interfering.